# Repositório BitBucket com SourceTree, Projeto Visual Studio

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

Estou criando um novo projeto no `Visual Studio 2015` , eu criei o repositório no `BitBucket`,  então criei o projeto , o problema e que quando um dos usuários do projeto da um `Push` ele não atualiza.

Por exemplo : Eu adicionei a Classe `Teste` no projeto `Dominio` e dei `Push`  mas quando o outro usuário der `Pull`  essa classe não aparece no `solution explorer`  apesar de estar na pasta do projeto. Alguém sabe algo a respeito ?

Procurei na aqui e em outros lugares e não achei nada a respeito se aqui não for  lugar certo de perguntar me avisem.

EDIT : Eu estou dando Push pelo SourceTree, na primeira vez que adicionei a camada infra que é uma Classlibrary , o csproj foi, mas depois ele não foi mais , aqui esta meu `.gitignore`

```
    ## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
[Xx]64/
[Xx]86/
[Bb]uild/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

Comment: Está fazendo *commit* do arquivo **`.csproj`** também?

Comment: Sim estou fazendo sim.

Comment: Acabei de percebe ele esta mandando apenas de uma das camadas , eu tenho duas camadas , infra e dominio. ele manda apenas da Dominio. Como faço para resolver isso ??

Comment: Não sei do que você está falando. São necessários mais detalhes, como está fazendo o *commit*? Os arquivos foram devidamente adicionados no repositório? Como está o arquivo ***.gitignore***?

Comment: Vou melhorar minha pergunta...

Comment: Veja as alterações se são o suficiente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É importante notar se o arquivo .csproj também está indo no Commit e se não houve conflito nele.O próprio Git agora disponibiliza um arquivo .gitattributes com informações para resolver esses conflitos.Se você descomentá-lo resolverá esse problema,veja abaixo :

```
###############################################################################
# Set the merge driver for project and solution files
#
# Merging from the command prompt will add diff markers to the files if there
# are conflicts (Merging from VS is not affected by the settings below, in VS
# the diff markers are never inserted). Diff markers may cause the following 
# file extensions to fail to load in VS. An alternative would be to treat
# these files as binary and thus will always conflict and require user
# intervention with every merge. To do so, just uncomment the entries below
###############################################################################
*.sln       merge=binary
*.csproj    merge=binary
#*.vbproj    merge=binary
#*.vcxproj   merge=binary
#*.vcproj    merge=binary
#*.dbproj    merge=binary
#*.fsproj    merge=binary
#*.lsproj    merge=binary
#*.wixproj   merge=binary
#*.modelproj merge=binary
#*.sqlproj   merge=binary
#*.wwaproj   merge=binary
```